# Determining important features from large number of features

Tags: classification, pca, feature-selection

From a large number of time series, I've generated an even larger number of features for each one. The result is a NxM matrix for times series N and feature M.

Using Matlab, I could feed this dataset into the *Classification Learner* and generate a nice model of the data but I want to be a bit more sophisticated as I'm sure a majority of the M features are irrelevant (or correlated).

I understand that using Principle Component Analysis, the calculated eigenvectors give insight into which features contribute the most to the variability in each Principle Component (at least, that's my perhaps *naive* understanding), but I feel like picking the features like this may be a small part of a bigger picture.

Are there any systematic approaches I can use to reduce this data? Perhaps some books I should read on this topic?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to the site. I don't quite understand how the data are structured. Is your timeseries a single univariate series of length $N$ and the rest of the $M-1$ columns of your matrix are the features ($M$ possibly greater than $N$)? Are these features time varying such as lagged effects or cross-correlated or time fixed?

Comment: The NxM matrix is a set of precalculated features from my N time series. The features calculated were inspired by the tool called HCTSA which calculates a large number of different features from time series.

In total, I calculated about 200 features for each time series. So assuming I have 1000 time series, the result is a 1000x200 matrix. This can be labelled and put into matlab's classification learner and a model can be generated.

What I want to know is how to study and remove redundant features, especially since I can tell many features are correlated.

Thanks for the response.